# How to write the metric tensor in n-dimensions using xAct?

Tags: matrix, tensors, xact

I am trying to reproduce some calculations from a paper, where they express the angular part of the metric as a solid angle in (d-2) dimensions:

[image]

where

[image]

I know how to calculate the metric tensor using the xAct package when the dimension is 4:

```
    << xAct`xTensor`
    << xAct`xTras`   
    << xAct`xCoba`
    DefManifold[M, 4, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l}] 
    DefChart[B, M, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]}] 
    DefScalarFunction /@ {bb} 
    DefScalarFunction /@ {pp} 
    metric = CTensor[TheMetric, {-B, -B}]
    SetCMetric[metric, B, SignatureOfMetric -> {3, 1, 0}]
    cd = CovDOfMetric[metric]
    ComponentArray[metric[-{a, B}, -{b, B}]] // Simplify // MatrixForm
```

But how do I do that when the dimension is n? Could someone shed some light or point me to something that addresses this?

Comment: I took a quick look at the documentation for the package, and this doesn't seem to be supported. You need to choose a specific (integer) value for the dimensionality. If you post more details about the calculation you're trying to perform/reproduce, users might be able to help you find an alternative approach. The arbitrary dimensionality seems to be confined to the angular terms, so perhaps there's a way to deal with that.

Comment: I need to calculate the Einstein tensor. The only packages I know are this one and 'GREAT'. Do you know any other package that can do this when the dimension is not specified? Thank you for your help.

Comment: GREAT dates back to 2003, and appears to be fairly small, so I suspect it also requires a specific sized manifold. There have been a number of packages for tensor algebra written over the years, but I believe all of them behave in a similar manner. The only suggestion I have is that you try doing the calculation for tensors of different sizes, and try to look for a systematic variation for the angular terms as you increase the tensor dimensions. I.e. try and see if there's a pattern evident. The definition you provided seems to change in a predictable way, so you may get lucky.

Comment: The basic problem is to figure out how to compute things like the Christoffel symbols and define covariant derivatives for arbitrary n. If you can figure out how to describe them mathematically, you can write your own code for the Riemann, contract indices etc using your metric, and get the Einstein tensor. That's probably quite hard to do, which is why you're not likely to find a package for this.